# How to check percentage overlap in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I'm new to SAS and need to find a way to do the following:

I have two datasets:

- `Users (user_id, friends)` (friends are `user_id`s seperated by a ",")
- `Reviews (user_id, review_id, business_id, text)`

I've merged both on `user_id`. Now I need to know **what percentage of the reviews of the friends of a user is about the same business(es) a user has reviewed**.

I guess I need a stored procedure for this (but I'm new to SQL also). Any tips how to start on it?

Comment: *"(friends are user_id's seperated by a ",")"* - for starters, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 0):

I would start with refactoring your users table to store friends as separate records rather than as a single list value:

```
data users(drop=friends);
set users;
do i=1 to countw(compress(friends_list),',');
  friend=scan(compress(friends_list),i,',');
  output;
end;
run;
```

you can then calculate that percentage by joining that table with `reviews` twice, once per user and once per friend:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.user_id
      ,sum(case when t3.business_id=t2.business_id then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as percentage
from users t1
inner join reviews t2
  on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
inner join reviews t3
  on t1.friend=t3.user_id
group by t1.user_id
;
quit;
```