# How to work across two datasets in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two datasets described below

```
data1:    
$restaurant  $reviewers  
A            Tom  
B            Jack.Mary.Joan  
C            Tom.Joan  
D            Rose

data2 (sorted by the friends numbers):  
$user        $friends  
Tom          Joan.Mary.Jack  
Jack         Tom.Rose  
Mary         Tom  
Joan         Tom
```

The question is to calculate the overlap in the reviews of these users with the reviews of their friends.

Take an example of Tom, the restaurants Toms friends reviewed are B and C, from which C was also reviewed by Tom. So here the percentage is C/B+C = 1/2, so the overlap is 50%.

I think I need a loop to work across two datasets, but with very basic knowledge of SAS, I don't know how. Has anybody an idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is extremely similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889637/how-to-check-percentage-overlap-in-sas/46890986#46890986)...

Comment: I am a beginner of SAS, and this question has kept me puzzles for several days. I am wondering if any experienced SAS users can solve this maybe very simple questions. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this.

```
data reviews;
infile datalines dsd dlm=",";
input restaurant $ reviewer $;
datalines;
A,Tom
B,Jack
B,Mary
B,Joan
C,Tom
C,Joan
D,Rose
;
run;

data users;
infile datalines dsd dlm=",";
input user $ friend $;
datalines;
Tom,Joan
Tom,Mary
Tom,Jack
Jack,Tom
Jack,Rose
Mary,Tom
Joan,Tom
;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.user
      ,sum(case when t3.restaurant=t2.restaurant then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as percentage
from users t1
inner join reviews t2
  on t1.user=t2.reviewer
inner join reviews t3
  on t1.friend=t3.reviewer
group by t1.user
;
quit;
```

I did'nt get your 0,5 value for Tom, but maybe you have a mistake.
So you can adapt the code as needed.

I followed the logic from here :
[How to check percentage overlap in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889637/how-to-check-percentage-overlap-in-sas/46890986#46890986)